# Why my updated data is not taking in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-8, criteria

I am writing one API which is responsible for searching the books of a price by using criterias. The user can search books with dollars but in database the price is stored in the form of cents. What I do is that I am taking the value in `dollars` and convert it into `cents`. That conversion is sent to the push criterias but the data is not coming.
Suppose I use normal query for same data it's getting data from DB. In order to use model or raw queries i want to use criterias.

Please help to find the mistake.

```
$cents=array($request->price* 100);
            $this->repository->pushCriteria(new WhereInCriteria('price',$cents));
$this->repository->paginate();  //no data is coming

//if i am using following query i am getting output
Book::whereIn('price',$cents)->get();
```

`WhereInCriteria.php`

```
 public function __construct($field, array $value)
    {
        $this->field = $field;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    
    public function apply($model, PrettusRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        return $model->whereIn($this->field, $this->value);
    }
```

Comment: Is it an open source package or what is repository in this case? else i would like to see the code of pushCriteria and paginate

Comment: BooksRepository.php file is placed inside the constructor so that's why i am using $this->repository

Comment: But wouldn't it make sense to include the repository in the question, if those method clearly don't work?

Comment: @user17426459 Do you have any updates to this question? Is it solved somehow? Please, inform us if you have tried something else or you still facing a problem.

Comment: @Tinxuanna, yes in `l5-package` it self  it's taking request [`appends(app('request')->query())` ]from the api so that's why it's not taking updated value